# _controlfp not changing the precision

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point

The code below demonstrates this

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#pragma fenv_access(on) // apparently ineffective

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint32_t cw;
    cw = _controlfp(0,0);               // cw = 0x0008001f
    cw = _controlfp(_PC_24,_MCW_PC);    // cw = SAME!
    cw = _controlfp(_PC_53,_MCW_PC);    // cw = STILL THE SAME!

    return 0;
}
```

I need to set the working precision, as a lot of old mesh generation code depends on it. Before migrating to 64 bit, I threw in `fstcw [cur_cw]` etc... and all was well. However, since vs2010 does not support inline assembly for 64 bit targets, it seems the only workable solution I have is to create a separate .asm file for this purpose. Is there yet another magic not-so-well documented compiler option I don't know about that will make _controlfp cooperate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the old x87 FPU is being used? I would expect all floating point to be performed using SSE instructions by default; on x86_64, there's no good reason *not* to use SSE.

Comment: It's kindof a mix. Anything that does interpolation/perturbation can be whatever the compiler wants, but the predicates are assembly-optimised versions of the Shewchuk codes, and they all use the old x87 instructions :X. Come to think of it, it's probably time to re-write them.

Comment: Yeah - SSE intrinsics are pure *luxury* compared to x87.

Answer (score 1):

_MCW_PC (Precision control) Not supported on ARM or x64 platforms.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx